# How can I create a SQL Server stored procedure which can produce a table combining three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three SQL tables as below.

Table #1: Benchmark

```
WorkLoadType    MaxUsersperVCpu vCPU    RAM MaxUserCapacity
------------------------------------------------------------
Light           6                2        8     12
Medium          4                4       16     16
Heavy           2                4       16     8
Power           1                6       56     6
```

Table #2: VMType

```
id  HostPoolName    Resource_Group  WorkLoadType
------------------------------------------------
1   Pool1               RG1         Light
2   Pool2               RG2         Light
3   Pool3               RG3         Light
4   Pool4               RG4         Light
```

Table #3: VM

```
HostPoolName    MemoryInMB  Name        NumberOfCores   Resource_Group  VMSize
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pool1              8192     VM1             2            RG1           Standard_D2s_v3
Pool1              8192     VM2             2            RG1        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool2              8192     VM3             2            RG2        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool3              8192     VM4             2            RG3        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool3              8192     VM5             2            RG3        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool3              8192     VM6             2            RG3        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool3              8192     VM7             2            RG3        Standard_D2s_v3
Pool3              8192     VM8             2            RG3        Standard_D2s_v3
```

I need to create a stored procedure which should produce a new table like this. Here `Capacity` column is the multiplication of `MaxUserPervCpu` and `NumberOfCores`

Table: Capacity

```
Name        HostPoolName    ResourceGroup   WorkLoadType    MaxUserPerVCpu  NumberOfCores   Capacity
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VM1         Pool1           RG1              Light                    6     2               12       
VM2         Pool1           RG1              Light                    6     2               12
VM3         Pool2           RG2              Light                    6     2               12
VM4         Pool3           RG3              Light                    6     2               12
VM5         Pool3           RG3              Light                    6     2               12
VM6         Pool3           RG3              Light                    6     2               12
```

A help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you need help with? What have you tried so far, why isn't it working? What documentation have you read and what don't you understand about it? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service; show is why what you have isn't working so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like simple `join`s:

```
select vm.*, b.*   -- choose the columns you want here
from vm join
     vmtype vt
     on vt.HostPoolName = vm.HostPoolName join
     Benchmark b
     on b.WorkLoadType = vt.WorkLoadType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the common key between all those tables and do an inner or outer join.
After the join if you like to include a formula you can but you may have to group the rest of the columns using group by statement.
Once thats done you can simply insert into the target table.

There are two options to insert... Insert into or select insert into

here is the difference between the two

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/select-into-insert-into-in-sql-server1